# Convert data frame common rows to columns

Tags: r, reshape

Say I have a data frame where one column is some repeating value (dates, IDs, etc).  Is there a way to convert a data frame into a now data frame with columns instead of replicating rows?  Basically I want to transpose something like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
1    aa   30
2    aa   40
3    aa   10
1    bb   20
2    bb   12
3    bb   15
1    cc   40
2    cc   31
3    cc   12
```

Into this:

```
    aa   bb   cc
1   30   20   40
2   40   12   31
3   10   15   12
```

Here is some code that makes a sample of the first data frame:

```
a <- c(rep(1:10, 3))
b <- c(rep("aa", 10), rep("bb", 10), rep("cc", 10))
set.seed(123)
c <- sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = 30, replace = TRUE)
d <- data.frame(a,b, c)
```

I am unsure how to transpose it.

Comment: You can use `reshape2::cast` or `tidyr::spread` to do it.

Comment: e.g. `tidyr::spread(d, key = b, value = c)` will give what you want.

Comment: Also `reshape` will get you close: `reshape(d , v.names="c", idvar="a", timevar="b", direction="wide" )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a <- c(rep(1:10, 3))
b <- c(rep("aa", 10), rep("bb", 10), rep("cc", 10))
set.seed(123)
c <- sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = 30, replace = TRUE)
d <- data.frame(a,b, c)
#how to transpose it#
e<-reshape(d,idvar='a',timevar='b',direction='wide')
e
```

Comment: Bingo. This is a textbook, simple example of `reshape`

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to accept this since it allows for unequal numbers of items in each sample.  These are all great though.

Answer (score 6):

This is also a case in which you can use `unstack`:

```
unstack(d, c ~ b)
#    aa bb cc
# 1  30 50 50
# 2  45 35 40
# 3  30 40 40
# 4  50 40 50
# 5  50 20 40
# 6  20 50 40
# 7  35 25 35
# 8  50 20 40
# 9  35 30 30
# 10 35 50 25
```

Comment: The code keeps getting shorter for every new answer

Comment: This is also pretty helpful but I'm going to use one of the earlier solutions just in case my data frame does not contain the same number of observations for each grouping.

Answer (score 5):

Using your data frame `d`,

```
library(tidyr)
> spread(d, key = b, value = c)
    a aa bb cc
1   1 30 50 50
2   2 45 35 40
3   3 30 40 40
4   4 50 40 50
5   5 50 20 40
6   6 20 50 40
7   7 35 25 35
8   8 50 20 40
9   9 35 30 30
10 10 35 50 25
```

Explanation, the argument `key = b` lets you specify a column in your data frame. `spread` will create a new column for each unique entry in the key column `b`. The argument `value = c` tells `spread` to retrieve the value in column `c` and write it in the corresponding new `key` column.

Answer (score 4):

If there are always equal numbers of observations in each group, this would be very easy with `split` then `as.data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(split(d$c, d$b))
#    aa bb cc
# 1  30 50 50
# 2  45 35 40
# 3  30 40 40
# 4  50 40 50
# 5  50 20 40
# 6  20 50 40
# 7  35 25 35
# 8  50 20 40
# 9  35 30 30
# 10 35 50 25
```

Comment: This is neat, so long as there are equal numbers in each group. `reshape` will be preferable when this can't be guaranteed.

Comment: Agreed.  But it looks like it is, according to both the given data sets.  Added that to the answer for clarity

Comment: This is cool, thanks!  However, it is possible to have different numbers of observations.

Answer (score 0):

With split and cbind:

```
> ll = lapply(split(d, d$b), function(x) x[3])
> dd = do.call(cbind, ll)
> names(dd) = names(ll)
> dd
   aa bb cc
1  30 50 50
2  45 35 40
3  30 40 40
4  50 40 50
5  50 20 40
6  20 50 40
7  35 25 35
8  50 20 40
9  35 30 30
10 35 50 25
```